# my 'Target Membership' column on xcode does not allow me checkbox

Tags: xcode

my 'Target Membership' column does not allow me checkbox[image]

Comment: What kind of file do you try to add?

Comment: video :) <mp4/m4v>

Comment: You should try the following: Delete Derived Data, restart Xcode, restart Mac. If this does not help, remove and re-add the file.

Comment: thank you. trying it out now!

Comment: wow! the laptop sang like a canary!!!